# Переименовать несколько столбцов в таблице MySql PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
ALTER TABLE table_name change field1 new_field text, field2 new_field2 varchar(100)
```

Как переименовать сразу несколько полей и можно ли вообще?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name change field1 new_field text,
                       change field2 new_field2 varchar(100)
```

Comment: спасибо помогло!

Comment: @Владимир без column

Comment: @KirillKorushkin без COLUMN не хочет. Задал вопрос тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763349/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-mysql-php.