# Удаление нескольких столбцов из таблицы MySql PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN field1, field2
```

Как удалить несколько столбцов из таблицы за один запрос?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы почти угадали. Надо вот так:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
DROP Column1, DROP Column2
```

Источник: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html

> Multiple ADD, ALTER, DROP, and CHANGE clauses are permitted in a
>   single ALTER TABLE statement, separated by commas. This is a MySQL
>   extension to standard SQL, which permits only one of each clause per
>   ALTER TABLE statement. For example, to drop multiple columns in a
>   single statement, do this:
>
> `ALTER TABLE t2 DROP COLUMN c, DROP COLUMN d`;

Comment: Спасибо большое